# Orchard content types: add field that dynamically scales

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Is it possible to add a field or a group of fields in a content type in Orchard that acts like a list?

Specific example:
Event content type has a text field speaker. But since we can have multiple speakers in an event we can add more text fields dynamically through, preferably, a plus (+) sign icon. An alternate could then go through the list and display them accordingly.

Is this possible?

I'm trying to create a content type Guide which can have varying number of steps. A step can have multiple fields (title, html, thumbnail, etc).

Thanks!

Any piece of advise or information would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs it, the best one for this scenario is building a 1-n relationship yourself: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations

The Content Picker field as suggested by Tanooki also works, but you have more control when using 1-n relationships.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Enumeration field that allows you to choose one/more from the list of provided string values.

Answer (score 0):

How about a `ContentPickerField`? Or maybe using `Taxonomy`?